# Formatting key values using map() with a lambda function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

Given the list of employees defined in the cell below, process the list of dictionaries to create a list of employee names formatted as title firstname lastname e.g. Mr Jonathan Calderon, etc

So far I can print out titles but thats about it...

my work:

```
new_list2 = list(map(lambda x: x["title"], employees)) 
print(new_list2)
```

output:

```
['Mr', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms']
```

List of Dictionaries:

```
employees = [
    {
        "email": "jonathan2532.calderon@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 101,
        "firstname": "Jonathan",
        "lastname": "Calderon",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 3691 5845"
    },
    {
        "email": "christopher8710.hansen@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 102,
        "firstname": "Christopher",
        "lastname": "Hansen",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 5807 8580"
    },
    {
        "email": "isabella4643.dorsey@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 103,
        "firstname": "Isabella",
        "lastname": "Dorsey",
        "title": "Mrs",
        "work_phone": "(02) 6375 1060"
    },
    {
        "email": "barbara1937.baker@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 104,
        "firstname": "Barbara",
        "lastname": "Baker",
        "title": "Ms",
        "work_phone": "(03) 5729 4873"
    }
]
```

expected output:

```
Mr Jonathan Calderon
Mr Christopher Hansen
Mrs Isabella Dorsey
Ms Barbara Baker
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing new_list2 = list(map(lambda x,y,z: x["title"]y["firstname"]z["lastname"], employees))  but that does not work..

Comment: The function you've defined takes three arguments, but map will only ever pass it one argument. Just use one argument in the lambda and do exactly what you are doing (obviously, replacing the other two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP asked for `map()`, here sir, is the solution using it and only it (no need for the importing of additional libraries):

```
result = map(lambda x: [x['title'],x["firstname"],x["lastname"]],employees)
print(*["{} {} {}\n".format(a,b,c) for a,b,c in result], sep="")

Output:
Mr Jonathan Calderon
Mr Christopher Hansen
Mrs Isabella Dorsey
Ms Barbara Baker
```

Comment: This is great, I want to understand what does the asterisk(*) and sep="" do in the print line?

Comment: Sure. The asterisk unwraps the contents of the list so the print statement can print out each element separated by a space. The sep="", tells the print statement to print "" (which is nothing) instead of the space, thereby eliminating the space between the elements. Without sep="", there would be a space after the first entry, making the following names indented by 1.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension and fetch the values of interest from each dictionary using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = ['title', 'firstname', 'lastname']

[' '.join(itemgetter(*l)(i)) for i in employees]
```

**Output**

```
['Mr Jonathan Calderon', 'Mr Christopher Hansen', 'Mrs Isabella Dorsey', 'Ms Barbara Baker']
```

---

Or if you prefer with `map`:

```
[' '.join(map(lambda x: i.get(x), l)) for i in employees]
# ['Mr Jonathan Calderon', 'Mr Christopher Hansen', 'Mrs Isabella Dorsey', 'Ms Barbara Baker']
```

Comment: im trying to get it with map() lambda function but thanks anyway :)

Comment: You can also use `map` @KevinW, check the updated answer

Comment: this is great I'm just trying to understand the part where i.get(x) and for i in employees

Comment: Check the doncs [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more info on this. `dict.get(i)` is just a method for dictionaries in order to fetch a value by specifying a key.